In php image is uploading in database but not uploading in the folder where i want to upload it, even after mentioning the full folder path in mac
I'm uploading image in php using (move_uploaded_file()) function, but image is not uploading in the folder where i want to upload it even after mentioning the folder path in macbook m1 chip



Please don't post images of code or errors!

Your upload code gives you feedback. What is it? Remember, we cannot run the code on your Mac, only you can.

You have a hidden input named "MAX_FILE_SIZE". It is not used. Why is it there?

@KIKOSoftware See this.

@Olivier Didn't know that. Anyway, I wouldn't implement it that way, since this value can potentially be changed by the client.

@KIKOSoftware The real problem here is that MAX_FILE_SIZE equals 30000 (just like in the PHP documentation), which means that images above 30KB will be refused. That's what happens when you copy code without understanding it...

I see there are two mistakes within your code.
First with the $uploaddir. Is it a relative path? If yes then why it contains htdocs? it should not. Path should look like /directory
Secondly, you forget to add a slash between the dir and basename. So your script is considering it as a whole name of the directory.
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.'/'.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

Check the doc here
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir);

